# An upper bound of $-p \log p$ with $p > 0$ very small

Tags: probability, logarithms, entropy

I am looking for an upper bound of $-p \log p$ in terms of probability $p$ with $1 > p>0$ when $p$ is very close to $0$ (at least $p < 1/e$).

It would be really great if I have a tight one.

I know a good upper bound when $p$ is close to 1; the upper bound is $1-p$.

Comment: When $0<\alpha<1$ you could use $-p\log p \le C_\alpha p^\alpha$, where $C_\alpha$ is a suitable constant.

Comment: @Gribouillis Could you give me more specific condition on $C_\alpha$ or a related reference?

Comment: I don't have a reference but study the function $p\mapsto -p^{1-\alpha}\log p$ in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Okay, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that for any $p>0$ we have$-p\log p \le \frac{1}{e}$. Let $\alpha\in{\mathbb R}$. The inequality holds with $p^{1-\alpha}$ instead of $p$ hence we have
\begin{equation}-(1-\alpha)p^{1-\alpha}\log p = - p^{1-\alpha}\log(p^{1-\alpha})\le \frac{1}{e}\end{equation}
When $\alpha < 1$ we deduce
\begin{equation}-p\log p\le \frac{p^\alpha}{e(1-\alpha)}\end{equation}
For example when $\alpha = 1/2$,
\begin{equation}-p\log p\le \frac{2\sqrt{p}}{e}\le\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{p}\end{equation}

Comment: The first line is not clear to me paritcularly due to the term $(1-\alpha) p^{-\alpha}$. Could you please more clarify? Is this term less than or equal to 1?

Comment: I think this holds only for $\alpha$ sufficiently close to $1$, not $\alpha =1/2$.

Comment: The first line comes from $-p^{1-\alpha}\log(p^{(1-\alpha)})\le \frac{1}{e}$. For the first line, $\alpha$ can be any real number. Then we need $\alpha < 1$ to divide by $1-\alpha$.

Comment: $\begin{equation}-p\log p\le \frac{2\sqrt{p}}{e}\end{equation}$ is valid for  $p\leq \frac 1 {e^2}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The above inequalities hold for all $p > 0$ and $\alpha \in (-\infty, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

We use the well known inequality $logp\geq\,1-\dfrac{1}{p}$. Then we multiply by $-p$ and we get $-plogp\,\leq\,-p+1$. So your upper bound holds for all $p$ not just for $p$ close to zero.

Now using L'Hospital rule we calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{p \to 0}-\dfrac{logp}{1/p}=\lim_{p \to 0}p=0.$,

So we can get an upper bound as small as we want by taking $p$ sufficiently close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can have good upper bounds building $P_n(p)$, the $[n,n]$ Padé approximant of $-p \log(p)$ built around $p=\frac 1e$. You need $n \geq 2$.

For example
$$P_2(p)=\frac{1}{e}\times\frac {1+\frac{e}{3} \left(p-\frac{1}{e}\right)-\frac{5e^2}{9} 
   \left(p-\frac{1}{e}\right)^2 } {1+\frac{e}{3}  \left(p-\frac{1}{e}\right)-\frac{e^2}{18} 
   \left(p-\frac{1}{e}\right)^2 } > -p\log(p) \quad \text{for} \quad p \in \left(0,\frac 1e\right)$$ To give you an idea
$$\Phi_2=\int_0^{\frac 1e} \Big[P_2(p)+p\log(p)\Big]^2\,dp=5.77\times 10^{-5}$$
$$\Phi_3=\int_0^{\frac 1e} \Big[P_3(p)+p\log(p)\Big]^2\,dp=6.58\times 10^{-6}$$

Any $P_n$ will be larger than $-p \log(p)$ in the range.

$e\, P_n(0)$ generates the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{2}{11},\frac{8}{93},\frac{19}{374},\frac{107}{3180},\frac{39}{1628},\frac{293}{16338},\cdots\right\}$$ which are closer and closer to $0^+$